# Java ternary operator confusion

Tags: java

here is my code

```
public class BinarySearch {
    public static int binsearch(int key, int[] a)
    {
        int lo = 0;
        int hi = a.length - 1;
        while (lo < hi)
        {
            int mid = (lo + hi) >> 1;
            key < a[mid] ? hi = mid : lo = (mid + 1);
        }
        return lo--;

    }
}
```

i got an error when compiling

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    Syntax error on tokens, Expression expected instead
    Syntax error on token "]", delete this token
    Syntax error, insert "]" to complete Expression
```

and if i change '<' to '>' as

```
key > a[mid] ? hi = mid : lo = (mid + 1);
```

got a total different error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    Syntax error on token ">", -> expected
```

I am really confused about the ternary operator usage in java.
after all, this code works fine in c++

Comment: could you first break your code out into non-ternary if statements? I assure you the ternary works in java, but what you have written here is not java code.

Comment: That’s not specific to the ternary operator. In Java, unlike C, you can not place expressions where statements are expected.

Comment: "this code works fine in c++" This is because C++ is a lot more relaxed about statement-expressions. Java, on the other hand, allows only direct and compound assignment expressions to be used as statements.

Comment: pretty sure this binsearch doesn't work fine even in C++

Answer (score 11):

The compiler is having hard time parsing your expression because it is used like a statement-expression.

Since ternary operator is an *expression*, it should not<sup>*</sup> be used in place of a *statement*. Since you would like to control the assignment, which is a statement, with the condition, you should use a regular `if`:

```
if (key < a[mid]) {
    hi = mid;
} else {
    lo = (mid + 1);
)
```

<sup>*</sup> In fact, Java does not allow ternary expressions to be used as statements. You could work around this issue by wrapping your expression in an assignment or an initialization (see [demo](http://ideone.com/amGOk8)), but this would result in code that is hard to read and understand, so it should be avoided.

Answer (score 1):

Ternary operator in java works only like this:

```
x=(a>b?a:b);
```

This operation puts the larger of `a` and `b`
This is not allowed:

```
a>b?x=a:x=b;
```

It maybe looks similar, but ternary operator branches in java can contain only value, not assigment

---

EDIT:
In your case I advice to use `if` statement

Answer (score 1):

In this case you should use an if statement.

```
if(key > a[mid])
    hi = mid;
else
    lo = mid + 1;
```

This is because the ternary operator is used for when you're setting a variable. For example:

```
foo = (firstVariable > secondVariable) ? 1 : 0;
```

(something along those lines).

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25):

> The conditional operator has three operand expressions. **?** appears between the first and second expressions, and **:** appears between the second and third expressions.
>
> **The first expression must be of type boolean or Boolean, or a compile-time error occurs.**
>
> **It is a compile-time error for either the second or the third operand expression to be an invocation of a void method.**

In other words, the conditional operator cannot be used to do something like this*:

```
key < a[mid] ? foobar1() : foobar2();
```

- *There is a workaround using reflection but at the end of the day, code succinctness does not trump readability.*